# "Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated::$guard"

Tags: laravel, openldap

I am building an laravel(v5.5) MultiAuth application. Whenever a user/admin login/logout, this piece of code from Adldap\Laravel\Listeners\BindsLdapUserModel throws ErrorException "Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated::$guard"

```
 public function handle($event)
{
    // Before we bind the users LDAP model, we will verify they are using the Adldap
    // authentication provider, the required trait, the users LDAP property has
    // not already been set, and we have located an LDAP user to bind.

    if (
        $this->isUsingAdldapProvider($event->guard)
        && $this->canBind($event->user)
        && $user = Resolver::byModel($event->user)
    ) {
        $event->user->setLdapUser($user);
    }
}
```

[image: sceenshot of dd($event->user)]

Comment: Their master branch had it modified, it checks for property guard availability first https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel/blob/master/src/Listeners/BindsLdapUserModel.php#L20 But, anyway have you tried to set property `$guard` on user model as public property?

Comment: also show code of login authentication

Comment: I have also change the $guard variable from protected to public but it gives me same exception.

Comment: Thanks for help . In laravel 5.7 $event->guard is available.But in this application guard is available inside $event->user object. I tried to catch it like $event->user->guard. It gives me null.